# Почему выводит ошибку: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."?

Tags: c#, winforms

я решил изучить C# и столкнулся с проблемой решения которой нигде не смог найти. Изначально задача звучит так: Дан одномерный массив, сформировать новый массив из элементов кратных **C** первого массива.
Я попутался решить этот массив и мне выдало ошибку

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."

Я прошу либо решить ошибку либо, полностью на ваше виденье переписать код и решить задачу.

```
int k=0, a=0,i=0,c,j=0;
string Omas = "", Tmas = "";
int[] ron = new int[20];
int[] bog = new int[k];
c = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
Random rnd = new Random();
for (i = 0; i < ron.Length; i++)
{
    ron[i] = rnd.Next(15);
    if (ron[i] % c == 0)
    {
        k++;
    }
    Omas = Omas + "   " + ron[i].ToString();
}
listBox1.Items.Add(Omas);
//Выводим изначальный массив

for (i = 0, j=0; i < 20; i++)
{
    if (ron[i] %c==0)
    {
        bog[j] = ron[i];
        Tmas = Tmas + "   " + bog[j].ToString();
        j++;
    }
}
listBox2.Items.Add(Tmas);
//Выводим конечный массив
```

[image: Скриншёт]

Comment: Как минимум, вы делаете в самом начале `int[] bog = new int[k]` - чему равен `k`? Подсказка: `int k = 0`. Далее, вы делаете `+ bog[i]`, где `i` у вас `i < 20`, то есть 0...19, ну а сколько раз у вас условие `ron[i] % c == 0` будет `true`? Вы уверены, что оно попадает в диапазон, который задали (0...19)? Я думаю, нет. В любом случае, программист должен уметь пользоваться отладкой, очень сильно советую обучиться данному навыку. Поставьте точку остановки в начале вашей логики, а потом жмите `F10` и `F11`(с заходом в метод), и двигайтесь так шаг за шагом по коду, и смотрите что и как делает код.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Объясню как работает этот код по моему мнению, я не раз меня способ решения. Я инициализирую массив `bog` и так как значения первого массива рандомны, заполняя массив `ron` я попутно проверяю сколько из индексов совпадают с условием `if (ron[i] % c == 0)` если оно верно то `k`  количество индексов нового массива. `int[] bog = new int[k];` То есть она точно должно быть от 0 до 19. И даже в режиме отладки я не понимаю в чём ошибка. Я отредактирую вопрос приложив скриншёт.

Comment: Да, только когда вы делаете `int[] bog = new int[k];`? **до** установки значения переменной `k` или **после**? Код работает последовательно, никакой магии тут нету, первая строка, `k=0`, далее что-то, а потом `new int[k]` (где `k==0`). Даже на скриншот свой посмотрите, там вам пишет `bog Просмотр - {int[0]}`, наведите мышь в конце концов на `bog` и гляньте какой у него размер, будет 0, ибо вы инициализировали его **ДО** установки `k` какого либо значения. Вот если вы `int[] bog = new int[k]`  перенесете после цикла `for`, тогда да, будет нужный, НО тут у вас будет 2-й пункт, о котором я писал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам все правильно написал EvgeniyZ - вы сначала создаете массив (статический) нулевой длины, а потом пытаетесь присвоить значение его элементам, которых нет. Отсюда и ошибка. Необходимо, как Вам и рекомендовали, перенести создание массива bog на место после цикла вычисления k, либо в первом же цикле записывать подходящие кратные значения, скажем в `List<int> bog`.

Короткое решение задачи:

```
static int[] DivArray(int min, int max, int c)
{
    // min - нижняя граница интервала генерации случайных чисел
    // max - верхняя граница интервала генерации случайных чисел
    // с - число, на которое будут делиться элементы полученной последовательности  
    
    // Формируем последовательность случайных чисел в диапазоне 
    // между [min и max], равную длине интервала min - max
    var arrRnd = Enumerable.Range(0, max - min + 1)
                           .Select(x => new Random().Next(min, max + 1));
    
    // Выбираем из последовательности arrRnd числа, делящиеся на c без остатка 
    var arrDiv = arrRnd.Where(x => x % c == 0);
    
    // Возвращаем полученный массив
    return arrDiv.ToArray();
}
```